# Failed to download metadata for repository 'pgdg-common' on CentOS 7

Tags: linux, stream, centos

When I try to install or update packages on my [CentOS Stream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CentOS_Stream) 8, then this error occurs:

```
cd ~
sudo yum update
```

Output:

```
PostgreSQL common RPMs for RHEL / Rocky 8 - x86_64                                                           613  B/s | 659  B     00:01
PostgreSQL common RPMs for RHEL / Rocky 8 - x86_64                                                           1.6 MB/s | 1.7 kB     00:00
PostgreSQL common RPMs for RHEL / Rocky 8 - x86_64                                                           503  B/s | 659  B     00:01

Error: Failed to download metadata for repo 'pgdg-common': repomd.xml GPG signature verification error: Bad GPG signature
```

I tried to install [Docker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Docker_%28software%29) or just update the packages or libraries on my CentOS 7 server.

#### Server details

```
cd ~
hostnamectl
```

Output:

```
   Static hostname: e2e-101-138
         Icon name: computer-vm
           Chassis: vm
        Machine ID: 7bxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
           Boot ID: c0xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    Virtualization: kvm
  Operating System: CentOS Stream 8
       CPE OS Name: cpe:/o:centos:centos:8
            Kernel: Linux 4.18.0-529.el8.x86_64
      Architecture: x86-64
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can try:

```
rpm -Uvh https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/reporpms/EL-8-x86_64/pgdg-redhat-repo-latest.noarch.rpm
```

But for me, this didn't fix the issue.
Until a proper solution is found, for me, renaming the following file worked:

```
cd /etc/yum.repos.d/
mv pgdg-redhat-all.repo pgdg-redhat-all.repo.old
yum update -y
```

At the very least, it should let you install and update packages now.

Comment: Thanks, your solution works.
Is this going to occupy more storage, like my old packages and new ones are both on the system?
If yes then how do I clean?

Comment: 2nd solution works fine with me too. thnx

Answer (score 20):

*Reference*

- [PostgreSQL RPM repository GPG key update - 3 January 2024](https://yum.postgresql.org/news/pgdg-rpm-repo-gpg-key-update/)

For CentOS 7:

```
yum --disablerepo=* -y install https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/reporpms/EL-7-x86_64/pgdg-redhat-repo-latest.noarch.rpm
```

Comment: After installing the new repository package (as per the answer) you can automatically accept the new keys using (for example):  yum -y list updates

Comment: Thank you, but in my case, this solution won't work

Answer (score 7):

I am seeing this issue on [Rocky Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rocky_Linux) 8 VMs too.

Our puppet runs started complaining about the signature of the repository download early on 2024-01-05.

This was the issue for us along with the solution (for us at least):

- *[Re: BUG #18270: RPM signing GPG key URL changed 2024-01-03](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/4f803fbc884177e5ead5e54dee52db5048d21110.camel%40gunduz.org)*
- *[PostgreSQL RPM repository GPG key update - 3 January 2024](https://yum.postgresql.org/news/pgdg-rpm-repo-gpg-key-update/)*

Answer (score 3):

The repository URL may be broken.

For CentOS 7:

Run:

```
sudo rpm -Uvh https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/reporpms/EL-7-x86_64/pgdg-redhat-repo-latest.noarch.rpm
```

Then:

```
yum update -y
```

Comment: still the error is here ....

Importing GPG key 0x73E3B907:

 Userid     : "PostgreSQL RPM Repository <pgsql-pkg-yum@lists.postgresql.org>"
 Fingerprint: F245 F0BF 96AC 1827 44CA FF2E 64FA CE11 73E3 B907
 From       : /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/PGDG-RPM-GPG-KEY-RHEL7
PostgreSQL common RPMs for RHEL / CentOS 8 - x86_64

Error: Failed to download metadata for repo 'pgdg-common': repomd.xml GPG signature verification error: Bad GPG signature

Answer (score 0):

I run Rocky 8 in both VMs and as a host. I tried spry's suggestion and followed the instructions in the link and it worked perfectly for me (thank you, spry). I'm providing it again here for convenience.

[PostgreSQL RPM repository GPG key update - 3 January 2024](https://yum.postgresql.org/news/pgdg-rpm-repo-gpg-key-update/)

Note that there are a lot of dnf command lines provided for you in the PostgreSQL article in the section "TL;DR: How can update my keys?". Be sure to choose your version carefully.

Although I trust postresql.org, I still had concerns that the --disablerepo=* switch would affect other repos so I tested it in my VM first. I listed active repos with

```
dnf repolist
```

then ran the dnf command provided by postresql.org for Rocky 8. After it completed, I ran the repolist command again. All was well.

Answer (score -1):

clean the cache and delete the pgdg related files and re-install is ok

```
sudo dnf clean all
sudo rm -rf /var/cache/dnf/*pgdg*
```